# ERRO 500 - Mas não sei onde está errado, alguém me ajuda!

Tags: java, mysql, spring, rest, spring-boot

```
@PostMapping//Create
public ResponseEntity<Categoria> criar(@RequestBody Categoria categoria, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Categoria categoriaSalva = categoriaRepository.save(categoria);
    URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri().path("/{codigo}").buildAndExpand(categoriaSalva.getCodigo()).toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(categoriaSalva);
}
```

arquivo Categoria.java

```
package com.example.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;
    private String nome;
    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String name) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Categoria other = (Categoria) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Envie mais informações sobre o erro, copie e cole o conteúdo do console

Comment: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'nome' cannot be null
...
2018-09-19 17:37:09.020 DEBUG 3460 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500

no Postman estou mandando o seguite:
{
 "nome": "Financiamento"
}

Comment: Olá, evite acrescentar informações nos comentários, em vez disso edite sua pergunta e acrescente as informações lá. Se precisar formatar algum código selecione o código e clique no botão `{}`. Peço que poste o conteúdo da classe `Categoria.java` e também da classe à qual pertence a variável `categoriaRepository` (seria `CategoriaRepository.java`?).

Comment: Procure postar código como texto e não como imagens. Peço a gentileza de corrigir para que outros usuários possam tirar proveito da pergunta também.

Comment: OK Piovezan, muito obrigado!

Comment: O pessoal ainda está martelando os votos negativos, acho melhor acrescentar o log de erro à pergunta também ou então alguém por favor explique o negativo para o ilustre padawan corrigir a pergunta. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O *setter* do campo `nome` não está fazendo a atribuição corretamente.

No classe `Categoria.java`, no método `setNome(String name)`, troque o parâmetro `name` por `nome`.

Dessa forma a atribuição ficará correta:

```
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
```